# Getting error when preparing active directory for lync server

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, lync-2010

Getting error when preparing active directory for lync server "failure occurred while attempting to check the schema state please ensure active directory is reachable".

I have also connected this server with a domain server.

Comment: I have also checked its DNS by dcdiag

Comment: Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

Comment: the issue has been resolved now. I was doing a little mistake, I logged in as local user but I should log in a user of domain controller server.